# ASP.NET flash mp3 player problem

Tags: asp.net

I'm going to use a flash mmp3 player in my ASP.NET web site, but this player is displayed like an image with no control at all:
here is my code put in ASPX file:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="http://www.phenomenontest.com/audio-player.js"></script>
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.phenomenontest.com/player.swf" id="audioplayer1" height="24" width="290">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.phenomenontest.com/player.swf"/>
<param name="FlashVars" value="playerID=audioplayer1&soundFile=http://www.phenomenontest.com/silas.mp3"/>
<param name="quality" value="high"/>
<param name="menu" value="false"/>
<param name="wmode" value="transparent"/>
</object>
```

where should I put it exactly? how should it be changed? you can take a look at phenomenontest.com, it is just like an image!
what is going wrong? please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code syntax is correct, but the Flash file http://www.phenomenontest.com/player.swf doesn't return--it times out with no response from the server. Get that SWF file to be sent from the server correctly and you'll be all set.

Are you sure the SWF file exists there, that the Flash MIME types are set correctly (IIS has problems with MIME types it doesn't understand--though it usually gives 404 errors, not timeouts in that case), or if for some reason the SWF file is dynamically being generated on the server somehow that the code that creates it isn't in an infinite loop or something that would cause the server to not respond?